# In storyboard, how to assign a view controller's subview a different delegate/controller m file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uistoryboard

In my storyboard, I have a view (a subclass of UIScrollView called AQGridView) which is nested inside a view controller scene. I want to assign the AQGridView a controller delegate and datasource which is defined in a separate .m and .h file than the parent view controller. How do I do this? Storyboard only lets me drag connectors to AQGridView's parent view controller.

**EDIT:**
I've tried doing something in the parent view controller like this (where myGrid is an IBOutlet pointing to the AQGridView and myGridController is a property of the parent view controller):

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
  // note: kzMyGridController is a subclass of AQGridViewController
  myGridController = [[kzMyGridController alloc] init];
  myGrid.delegate = myGridController;
  myGrid.dataSource = myGridController;
}
```

But it doesn't appear to be working because none of its delegate methods are being called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed on the StoryBoard, just do it on the code. It makes more sense, because it actually forces you to have an object (the delegate) and set it when you need it.

---

It should be:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
  // note: kzMyGridController is a subclass of AQGridViewController
  myGridController = [[kzMyGridController alloc] init];
  myGrid.delegate = myGridController;
  myGrid.dataSource = myGridController;
}
```

Comment: I've added an explanation describing how I've tried it programmatically. Still isn't working.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I think I've figured it out...the awakefromnib method is being called before AQGridView is being initialized.

Comment: Isn't this instantiating two viewcontroller at once when only one is needed. This is creating a new view controller in the parent's awakeFromNib. Wouldn't it be efficient to create two different scene in storyboard and instantiate the one you need ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I had to call reloadData on the AQGridView. The view is created before its delegate, so its initial data getting methods fire without a receiver.